# laravel - how to get list of 3rd level deep relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My model structure is as follows:

```
Question
  hasMany Decision
    hasMany Impact
      morphTo Related
```

So I'm trying to get a list of `Questions` with all of their `Related` objects deep inside.

Example:

```
{'question':1, relateds:[obj, obj, obj]}
{'question':2, relateds:[obj, obj, obj]}
{'question':3, relateds:[obj, obj, obj]}
```

I tried hasManyThrought relation, but it only works with two deep levels.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$questions = Question::with(['decisions.impacts.related'])->get();
```

or Something like

```
$questions = Question::all();

foreach ($questions as $question) {
    $question->load(['decisions.impacts.related']);
}
```

Didn't test.

---

Edit

```
foreach ($questions as $question) {
    $relateds = [];
    foreach ($question->decisions as $decision) {
        foreach ($decision->impacts as $impact) {
            $relateds[] = $impact->related;
        }
    }
    $result[] = ['question' => $question, 'relateds' => $relateds];
}
```

or

```
questions = Question::with('decisions.impacts.related')->get();

$result = $questions->map(function ($question) {
    return [
        'question' => $question,
        'relateds' => $question->decisions->pluck('impacts')->flatten()->pluck('related')->flatten()
    ];
});
```

Comment: this method works but it brings a nested relation, and I'm trying to get flat list with `question` and `relateds` only.

Answer (score 2):

There is a package for this: https://laravel-news.com/hasmanydeep-package
example usage: Country → hasMany → User → hasMany → Post → hasMany → Comment

```
class Country extends Model
{

    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;
 
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep('App\Comment', ['App\User', 'App\Post']);
    }
}
```

Haven't tested it though